# Power Automate custom connector deployment

Tags: powershell, office365, power-automate

Any idea on deploying Power Automate Custom Connectors into the customer’s tenant?

Microsoft Docs says it is possible via REST APIs or PowerShell. However, I could not find any details about it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/developer/dev-enterprise-intro

Can anyone guide me in correct direction?

Comment: I am on the same boat,  Did you ever managed to find out how to do this ?

Comment: See [`PowerPlatform Solutions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/solutions-overview). It won't be deployed via PowerShell, but you can create an importable package for your client to use. Of course, because its a Solution, the client must provision an Environment with a DataVerse database and all that accompanies.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by looking at this documentation from Microsoft about [creating a custom connector from scratch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/define-blank).  I found this by Googling "how to create a custom connector in power automate".

This assumes that you have a REST API already in place and that you have access to a Swagger 2.0 description of that API.  This file will tell the connector everything it needs to know about the API (what Actions it has, what inputs each action requires and what responses it provides).  These actions are what you "plug" into your "flow".

I grant that this a bit tricky to get started with but you can create a simple "Hello World" style Web API, publish it and then try connecting to that.  Bear in mind however that there are some API structures that don't appear to suit Power Automate such as having multiple response types which you can choose from with the Accept header.  I don't think Power Automate supports this.